# xml structure windows phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

Can someone help me save the following sample on Windows Phone 8 using C#? I'm really newbie with xml and I don't know how to save them in this structure

```
<Building Name="Main Building" Longitude="" Latitude="">
  <Lecture Name="HCI" Instructor="">
  <Info Time="Tuesday" Room="311"></Info>
  <Info Time="Sunday" Room="324"></Info>
  </Lecture>
  <Lecture Name="Software Engineering" Instructor="">
   <Info Time="Tuesday" Room="311"></Info>
  <Info Time="Sunday" Room="324"></Info>
  </Lecture>
</Building>
<Building Name="R" Longitude="" Latitude="">
<Lecture Name="Artificial Intelligence" Instructor="">
  <Info Time="Tuesday" Room="RB5"></Info>
  <Info Time="Sunday" Room="RC4"></Info>
</Lecture>
</Building>
```

Comment: Can you explain where you want to save this xml?

Comment: I save it locally on isolated storage